# Is it safe to expose rabbitmq amqp port over the internet?

Tags: rabbitmq, iot

I have a lot of different machines in multiple geographical locations. I need to command them from my backend and get data from them. I was thinking about connecting them all to a rabbitmq amqps connection to enable the bi-directionnel communication of my machines.

Is it a good approach? Is rabbitmq secure enough to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it a good approach?

yes! RabbitMQ makes it very easy to communicate between systems, through the internet. As long as each machine / process can access the same RabbitMQ (server / cluster), you should be ok.

> Is rabbitmq secure enough to do that?

Yes, as long as you follow standard security practices like any application that you expose to the internet.

Use firewalls, use SSL, set secure usernames and passwords with limited permissions, etc.

Comment: Are usernames / passwords implemented through RabbitMQ, or do you need some third party security layer?